# JQuery: How to make current tab unclickable

Tags: jquery, html, tags

I'm a JQuery novice, have no programming language experience so I'm not sure what should I change in this script to make the "current" tab unclickable

The script:

```
//When page loads...
$(".thumbCategory").hide(); //Hide all content
$("ul.tabsCont li:last").addClass("current").show(); //Activate last tab
$(".thumbCategory:last").show(); //Show last tab content - cause using right float -reversing

//On Click Event
    $("ul.tabsCont li").click(function() {

    $("ul.tabsCont li").removeClass("current"); //Remove any "active" class
    $(this).addClass("current"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
    $(".thumbCategory").hide(); //Hide all tab content

    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
    $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content
    return false;
});
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: `$.setAttr()` and HTML `disabled`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a click handler that does event.stopImmediatePropagation() and returns false.  You can also set the element to disabled

You can use the class .ui-state-disabled

Comment: Hm can you type it exactly where should I do that? I'm very novice here. Thx!